How to subset BAM file based on read length range (120-180) bp?
Hi I'm wondering how I can subset a BAM file based on read length. Precisely I want just read lengths of 120 to 180 bp reads in the new BAM file.
I'm trying several way, but none of them giving the output
samtools view -h $BAM/S14B_ZKDN240002415-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_bwaM.sort.rmdup.bam | 
awk '{if (length($10) >= 120 && length($10) <= 180) print $0}' |
samtools view -b - > $BAM/S14B_ZKDN240002415-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_bwaM.midSny.subset.bam

[E::sam_parse1] missing SAM header
[W::sam_read1] parse error at line 1
[main_samview] truncated file.

samtools view -h $BAM/S14B_ZKDN240002415-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_bwaM.sort.rmdup.bam |
awk 'NR==1 || (length($10) >= 120 && length($10) <= 180)' |
samtools view -b - > $BAM/S14B_ZKDN240002415-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_bwaM.midSny.subset.bam

E::sam_parse1] missing SAM header
[W::sam_read1] parse error at line 2
[main_samview] truncated file.

However, when I'm providing only single condition then it's working well,
 samtools view -h S10B_ZKDN240002407-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_bwaM.sort.rmdup.bam | 
    awk '{if (length($10) <= 180) print $0}' |
    samtools view -b - > temp.bam

But, if I use this temp.bam file for 2nd condition, then it's not working
 samtools view -h temp.bam |
 awk '{if (length($10) >= 120) print $0}'  |
 samtools view -b - >  S10B_ZKDN240002407-1A_H5VMFDSXC_L1_test2.midSny.subset.bam

[E::sam_parse1] missing SAM header
[W::sam_read1] parse error at line 1
[main_samview] truncated file. 


Your file's headers are also being passed through awk. Header lines' fields are all fairly short (and these lines may have fewer than ten fields, so length($10) would be zero), so they are all being removed by the awk conditions of the form length($10) >= 120.
To do this sort of thing you should have the headers bypass your filtering, which is a pain:
(samtools view --header-only $file; \
 samtools view --no-header $file | awk …) | samtools view -b -o $outfile

Or add to your awk conditions so that header lines are always kept, which is slightly less painful:
samtools view --with-header $file | \
awk '/^@/ || (length($10) >= 120 && length($10) <= 180)' | \
samtools view -b -o $outfile

Much easier to use samtools's built-in filtering expressions to do your filtering instead:
samtools view -e 'qlen >= 120 && qlen <= 180' -b -o $outfile $file

